# Xcode latest version switch language missing and project gives an error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Xcode version 6.2 (6C131e) is latest update for Xcode in App Store. Now when I created new project >> Single View Application.

A dialog show initial project setup: Project name and all that but it won't shows option to select language like `Swift` or `Objective C`

[image]

Also If I continue with Universal application project creation it shows an error on first run.

```
Class 'AppDelegate' defined without specifying a base class. 
Can not find declaration for AppDelegate'.
```

Is it a stable version? Or do I have to choose any preference or option from Xcode?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. But my Xcode doesn't show the "Which device family to create a project for" either. Do you have a custom Xcode template installed?

Comment: @MartinR - Thanks for reply, Actually the message was a pop up. I have edited question and post new image.

Comment: @MartinR: Can you able to see language choose option like in Xcode 6.1?

Comment: Then may be I need to remove and download it again?

Comment: I have no idea. But my new project dialog in Xcode 6.2 does not show the "Class Prefix" field, so something must be different in your installation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73228/discussion-between-kampai-and-martin-r).